# Multiple Rewrite modifications

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite urls but  i have problem pls help

here's what i'm trying to do .. this is my .htaccess now

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
# Turn off mod_security filtering.
SecFilterEngine Off

# The below probably isn't needed,
# but better safe than sorry.
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
LimitRequestBody 10000000000000

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) profiles/index.php?folder=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

and i wanna rewrite this url `//muscleathletes.com/index.php?page=supplements` to ` //muscleathletes.com/supplements (or page_name)

when i add the rule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1` nothing changes the url still the same
can you give me a little help with this?

Comment: The url doesn't change if you change something in the `.htaccess` file. You need to acces that url `muscleathletes.com/supplements` and this will point to `muscleathletes.com/index.php?page=supplements`.

Comment: Are you entering `muscleathletes.com/index.php?page=supplements` in your browser instead of `muscleathletes.com/supplements`?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Are you entering muscleathletes.com/index.php?page=supplements in your browser instead of muscleathletes.com/supplements

> Blockquote

YES! Sure